# Как отрендерить активные чекбоксы после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу заново отрендерить активные чекбоксы.

Сейчас: на странице с чекбоксами я вывожу в отдельном блоке кол-во выделенных чекбоксов и сортирую их названия из поля `label`

алгоритм такой: 
Ищу класс `ctf--b-filt-c-item` и прохожу по нему, в каждом нахожу checked инпуты и добавляю в массив.
Наименование пункта называется как текст, внутри `ctf--b-filt-c-item` с классом `b-txt`.
Это что касается вывода активных лейблов.

Естественно это все **не отображается после перезагрузки страницы**.
1) Т.е. я выделяю чекбоксы, все прекрасно работает
2) я нажимаю *применить* => страница обновляется, нужные чекбоксы выделены.
3) Но блока с отсортированными фильтрами нет.

Нужно после рендеринга чекбоксов получить все активные лэйблы и отрисовать их в `#unit`.
Я их получаю, но отобразить не могу

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

Прошу вашей помощи, спасибо

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
            $('#unit').empty();
            var count = 0;
            // проверяет каждый элемент .ctf--b-filt-c-item
            $('.ctf--b-filt-c-item').map(function(i, el) {
                let unit = $(this).find('input:checked').map(function(i, el) {
                    return ('<div class="ctf-b-btn-filter-items">' + $('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text() + '</div>');
                }).get();
                // если есть выбранные чекбоксы
                if (unit.length > 0) {
                    count += unit.length;
                    // то берёт текст из элемента .ctf--b-filt-c-head и после него 
                    // через запятую выводите все лейблы выбранных чекбоксов.
                    $('#unit').append('<div class="father father_tmp">' + $(this).find('.b-txt').text() + '</div>');
                    $('#unit').find('.father_tmp').append(unit.join(''));
                    $('.father_tmp').removeClass('father_tmp');
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

```css
.father { width: 500px; height: 100%; font-size: 12px; display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;margin-bottom: 10px; }
    .ctf-b-btn-filter-items { padding:2px;width:100; height:100%; border:none; cursor:pointer; font-size:13px; color: #ffffff; border-radius:2px; background: #35aaed; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #35aaed 0%,#0b80c4 100%); text-align:center; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin:0 22px 0 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Единица измерения:</span></div>
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
        <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
            <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_0" value="11770">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_0_0" data="text">
                        <i></i>
                        Килограмм
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_1" value="11771">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_0_1" data="text">
                        <i></i>
                        Тонна
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Полярность:</span></div>
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
        <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
            <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_0" value="11773">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_2_0" data="polarity">
                        <i></i>
                        Обратная
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_1" value="11776">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_2_1" data="polarity">
                        <i></i>
                        Прямая
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="unit"></div>
```

Comment: если вы говорите, что check на checkbox сохраняется, то может запускать функцию при загрузке страницы?

Comment: я понимаю что нужно сделать тоже самое только не на все чеки, а только на активные, но это не срабатывает.

Comment: у вас стоит on('change'), добавьте ту же функцию, только при загрузке страницы чтобы запускалась

Comment: Вы не дополнили в вопросе код применения `checkbox`-ов

Comment: Там в url передается get-запросом с value выбранных чекбоксов и они сохраняются, но дело в том, что я просто хочу отрендерить выбранные чекбоксы, независимо от кнопки "применить"

Comment: @Horchynskyi, а как это реализовать?

Comment: сделать через onload?

Comment: да так же через ready, просто я твою функцию не очень понимаю слабо с jquery знаком) думаю начать функцию с $('#unit').empty(); и до последних скобок которые к ней относятся

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$('#unit').empty();
и дальше. ну а если сработает, то просто создаешь функцию одну и будешь запускать её при загрузке и при изменении значения

Comment: и у меня после обновления страницы бокси так же обновляются,как у вас они сохраняются?

Comment: они передаются в гет-запросе, даже не знаю как это реализовать здесь в SO.

Comment: я немного обновил код в вопрос, сделал с пояснениями