# Как разбить строку на множество строк?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы каждый `label` (т.е., например, "Тонна" и "Килограмм") выводился в отдельной кнопке.
Сейчас эта кнопка растягивается. Я понимаю, что у меня каждый новый `label` попадает в строку. Но как правильно разделить эту строку не знаю?
Если работаю перебирать массив, то получается, что множится вся строка, т.е. получается так:

```
Единица измерения: Килограмм
Единица измерения: Тонна
Полярность: Обратная
Полярность: Прямая
```

Подскажите, как исправить?

```js
checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
              $('#unit').empty();
              var count = 0;
                $('.ctf--b-filt-c-item').map(function(i, el) {
                  let unit = $(this).find('input:checked').map(function(i, el) {
                    return ($('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text());
                  }).get();
                  if (unit.length > 0) {
                    count += unit.length;
                    $('#unit').append('<div class="father">' + $(this).find('.b-txt').text() + '<div class="ctf-b-btn-filter-items">' + unit.join(',') + '<div>' + '</div>');

                  }
                });
            });
```

```css
.father { width: 250px; height: 100%; font-size: 12px; display: inline-block;vertical-align: top; }
.ctf-b-btn-filter-items { padding:2px;width:100; height:100%; border:none; cursor:pointer; font-size:13px; color: #ffffff; border-radius:2px; background: #35aaed; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #35aaed 0%,#0b80c4 100%); text-align:center; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin:0 22px 0 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
      <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Единица измерения:</span></div>
      <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
        <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
          <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_0" value="11770">
              <label for="idchkk_2_0_0" data="text">
                <i></i>
                Килограмм
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_1" value="11771">
              <label for="idchkk_2_0_1" data="text">
                <i></i>
                Тонна
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Полярность:</span></div>
  <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
      <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ">
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_0" value="11773">
          <label for="idchkk_2_2_0" data="polarity">
            <i></i>
            Обратная
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_1" value="11776">
          <label for="idchkk_2_2_1" data="polarity">
            <i></i>
            Прямая
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="unit"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было дать обертку `<div class="ctf-b-btn-filter-items">` для каждого добавляемого текста `checkbox` а не для всех, а вы в эту обертку впихивали все тексты чекбоксов соединяя их как текст с запятой.

Вот поправленный код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Единица измерения:</span></div>
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
        <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
            <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_0" value="11770">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_0_0" data="text">
                        <i></i>
                        Килограмм
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_0_1" value="11771">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_0_1" data="text">
                        <i></i>
                        Тонна
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ctf--b-filt-check-list--double">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-item open ctf--b-filt-c-item--active">
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-head"><span class="b-txt">Полярность:</span></div>
    <div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
        <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr">
            <ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_0" value="11773">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_2_0" data="polarity">
                        <i></i>
                        Обратная
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_2_1" value="11776">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_2_1" data="polarity">
                        <i></i>
                        Прямая
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="unit"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
            $('#unit').empty();
            var count = 0;
            $('.ctf--b-filt-c-item').map(function(i, el) {
                let unit = $(this).find('input:checked').map(function(i, el) {
                    return ('<div class="ctf-b-btn-filter-items">' + $('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text() + '</div>');
                }).get();
                if (unit.length > 0) {
                    count += unit.length;
                    $('#unit').append('<div class="father father_tmp">' + $(this).find('.b-txt').text() + '</div>');
                    $('#unit').find('.father_tmp').append(unit.join(''));
                    $('.father_tmp').removeClass('father_tmp');
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<style>
    .father { width: 500px; height: 100%; font-size: 12px; display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;margin-bottom: 10px; }
    .ctf-b-btn-filter-items { padding:2px;width:100; height:100%; border:none; cursor:pointer; font-size:13px; color: #ffffff; border-radius:2px; background: #35aaed; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #35aaed 0%,#0b80c4 100%); text-align:center; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin:0 22px 0 0; }

</style>
```

Comment: вы могли бы помочь с рендером этих элементов после перезагрузки страницы ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694929/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B